# FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1) <br /> ^

Tags: flutter, dart

```js
validateUserEmail()  async
  {
    try
    {
      var res = await http.post(
       Uri.parse(API.validateEmail),
       body: {
         'user_email': emailController.text.trim(),
       },
     );
     if(res.statusCode == 200)//The HTTP 200 OK success status response code
       // indicates that the request has succeeded.
     {
      var resBodyOfValidateEmail = jsonDecode(res.body);
      if(resBodyOfValidateEmail['emailFound'] == true)
        {
         Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Email already in use.");
        }
      else
      {
        //register and save new user to database
        registerAndSaveUserRecord();

      }

     }
    }
    catch(e)
    {
      print(e.toString());
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: e.toString());
    }
  }

  registerAndSaveUserRecord() async
  {
   User userModel = User(
     1,
     nameController.text.trim(),
     emailController.text.trim(),
     passwordController.text.trim(),
   );

   try
       {
      var res = await http.post(
         Uri.parse(API.signUp),
         body: userModel.toJson(),
       );
      if(res.statusCode == 200)
        {
       var resBodyOfSignUp = jsonDecode(res.body);
       if(resBodyOfSignUp['success'] == true)
       {
         Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "You have signup successfully.");
       }
       else 
         {
           Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Error try again");
         }
        }
       }
       catch(e)
    {
      print(e.toString());
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: e.toString());
    }
  }
```

Guys i keep getting this error in Android studio when i try to register a new user to my flutter application

[The image shows the area where I think the problem is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xSGz.png)

I tried double checking the code to see whether there might be any typos or breaks on the code.

what might be the problem?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For further information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: We cannot fix invisible code... please [edit] your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that you are trying to decode a json but the api is sending an html instead of a json string, so that's why it fails decoding. I would recommend to check what is the api sending to you before trying to decode the body.